# Can’t boot RPM distros from usb or DVD

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation, manjaro

I tried Manjaro and Fedora 27-28.
There grub> prompt appear and it frozen in F28: can’t type anything.
But I can type in F27.
Tried UEFI and BIOS compatability mode.
Secure boot on/off change nothing.
I tried to write usb-stick using dd. Check sums are fine.
Checked usb-stick for badblocks - nothing.

Comment: Neither Fedora nor Manjaro is a "RHEL-based distro". Can you clarify if this is a diagnostic step you took after you couldn't get RHEL or CentOS or something to work, or if you meant those distros?

Comment: @mattdm what about step I took ? I aslo updated question.

Comment: Can you try making the USB stick with Fedora Media Writer? Also, what is the hardware?

Comment: @mattdm I was able to successfully write image through Fedora on VirtualBox using mediawriter. I was able to install it. Thought it sucks: it freeze on shutdown like any Linux distro of these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully write image through Fedora on VirtualBox using mediawriter. I was able to install it.